# Disabling slide - ionicLoading?

Tags: ionic-framework

How can I **disable** swipe on **ionicLoading** is showing?

When I open a screen where the loading appears, on the touch I would like it not to drag sideways.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved!**
I placed "loading" located where the problem occurred and after loading a json array it disappears.